# Keep only rows containing certain string from a list of strings provided

Tags: r

How do I keep only rows that contain a certain string given a list of strings. What I'm trying to say is I don't want to use `grepl()` and hardcode the values I would like to exclude. Let's assume that I want to only keep records that contain `abc` or `bbc` or `bcc` or 20 more options in one of the columns, and I have `x <- c("abc", "bbc", ....)`.

What can I do to only keep records containing values of `x` in the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%in%`:

```r
df_out <- df[df$v1 %in% x, ]
```

Or, you could form a regex alternation with the values in `x` and then use `grepl`:

```r
regex <- paste0("^(?:", paste(x, collapse="|"), ")$")
df_out <- df[grepl(regex, df$v1), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The stringi package has good functions for extracting string pattern matches

`newdat <- stringi::stri_extract_all(str, pattern)`

https://rdrr.io/cran/stringi/man/stri_extract.html

You can even pass the function a list of strings as your pattern to match